# Migrating JQuery File Upload to AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, jquery-file-upload

I'm migrating an existing project over to AngularJS and struggling to adapt the working JQuery File Upload code I wrote to the AngularJS paradigm.

Here's the working JQuery File Upload code I want to migrate into an Angular controller (in Coffeescript):

```
  $("#new_attachment").fileupload
    url: '/api/v1/attachments'
    dataType: 'json'
    add: (e, data) ->
      types = /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png|tif?f|pdf)$/i
      file = data.files[0]
      if types.test(file.type) || types.test(file.name)
        data.context = $(tmpl("template-upload", file))
        $('#attachments').append(data.context)
        data.submit()
      else
        alert("#{file.name} is not a format we currently support.")
    progress: (e, data) ->
      if data.context
        progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10)
        data.context.find('.meter').css('width', progress + '%')
    done: (e, data) ->
      $('#attachments').append $(tmpl("template-thumbnail", data.files[0]))
      if data.context
        data.context.hide()
    fail: (e, data) ->
      alert "Upload failed on one or more images."
```

Beyond injecting the fileupload module into the angular app (`angular.module('demo', ['blueimp.fileupload'])`), I pretty much stumped at how to bring this code into an Angular controller.

Any advice on how to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, there were a lot of great tutorials I found on doing this, but found that the complexity of adapting JQuery File Upload to an AngularJS flow wasn't worth the effort and found that [Angular File Upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload) offered the same functionality with a far simpler implementation.

Here's a good links I referenced when trying the JQuery File Upload route, if anybody wants to give it a try: http://code.xplorate.com/2013/05/angularjs-tutorial-4-file-upload-using.html#.VKbUyYrF_0r

If someone has a better answer to the question, please post and I'll make it the accepted answer.